# how to eliminate constraint in Z3

Tags: z3

I have a constraint like `(t>=0 or t>=1)` and `(t<=2 or t>=2)`,in fact the constraint can be simplified into "`t>=0`", how to use z3 to get the simplified result in CNF form by using z3?

```
(declare-const t Int)                                                                                  
(assert (and 
            (or
               (>= t 0)
               (>= t 1)
            )
            (or
                (>= t 2)
                 (<= t 2)
            )
            (>= t 0)
            (<= t 1)
        )
)                                                                                         
(apply (par-then (! simplify :elim-and true) tseitin-cnf))
```

However, the script doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `simplify` tactic only perform "local simplifications". That is, when simplifying an expression `t`, it will ignore the context of `t`. For example, it can simplify `a + 1 - a` into `1`, but it will not simplify `a != 0 or b = a + 1` into `a != 0 or b = 1`. 
Contextual simplification is expensive, the `simplify` tactic is meant to be efficient and simple. Other tactics may be used to achieve what you want.

The tactic `propagate-ineqs` will propagate inequalities. However, it will not process terms nested in the formula. The tactic `split-clause` can be used to break the formula in cases\goals. The tactic `propagate-values` will propagate the value of an assertion, example: `a = 0 and b >= a` is simplified to `a = 0 and b >= 0`.

The command `(help-tactic)` will display all available tactics.

Here is a strategy for simplifying your example into `t >= 0 and t <= 1`.

```
(apply (then simplify propagate-values split-clause propagate-ineqs))
```

Note that the combinator `par-then` is only useful for combining tactics that produce many sub-goals.
`(par-then t1 t2)` applies `t1` to the input goal, and applies `t2` (in parallel) to every subgoal produced by `t1`. The `split-clause` tactic produces more than one subgoal. Then (for bigger examples) it may be more efficient to use:

```
(apply (then simplify propagate-values (par-then split-clause propagate-ineqs)))
```

Comment: thanks, leonardo, I wonder can .net api of this problem  run in .net framework 3.5 or just only 4.0?

Comment: if I want to process terms nested in the formula in the example as follows, I want to simplify the (or (>= t 2)(<= t 2)), can z3 do it?                (declare-const t Int)                                                                                  
(assert (and 
            (or
               (>= t 0)
               (>= t 1)
            )
            (or
                (>= t 2)
                 (<= t 2)
            )
        )
)

Comment: That is why I added the `split-clause` tactic. It splits the clause in two cases. After that, `propagate-ineqs` can simplify the ineqs.

Comment: thanks,however, I want to get the simplest result. For example, give the constraint like  `(t>=0 or t>=1) and (t>=2 or t<=2)`, the expected simplified result is  `(t>=0)`, however the script doesn't work.                                                       `(declare-const t Int)
(assert (and 
            (or
               (>= t 0)
               (>= t 1)
            )
            (or
                (<= t 2)
                 (>= t 2)
            )
        )
)     
(apply (then simplify propagate-values (par-then split-clause propagate-ineqs)))`

Comment: I don't think the expected result of `(t>=0 or t>=1) and (t>=2 or t<=2)` is `(t>=0)`. Sure, in all branches `(t>=0)`, but we have more information than that. The tactic `split-clause` will split only one clause. In this example in your last comment, we have two. So, we can use the combinator `repeat` keep applying `split-clause` while applicable. Here is a link to the script that does that: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/XJVBp. Note that we have branches where `(t>=1 and t<=2)`.